# What is the purpose of a factory method in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following a book that uses a factory method to implement a class that is a singleton.

I understand that the main purpose of this is to have just one instance of the class; But what exactly the keyword "factory" does in flutter?

This is the piece of code that I'm referring:

```dart
static final DbHelper _dbHelper = DbHelper._internal();

DbHelper._internal();

factory DbHelper() => _dbHelper;
```

I supose that the `_dbHelper` is the single instance that is being create with the `_internal` `named constructor` and that the factory method returns this single instance, is that correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors

Comment: Don't use a singleton for your database. Use dependency injection. Possibly package provider if you object to passing it explicitly to widget constructors.

Comment: if you're saying don't use singleton, then tell us why! @Ted Henry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have it correct!

You can read more about factory constructors here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors